# How to generate beans with persistence mapping from xsd`s?

Tags: java, xsd, persistence, maven-jaxb2-plugin, hyperjaxb

I would like to ask such question, I have XML xsd`s, which generate beans with org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 , 
but now I need to add to these beans java.persistence mapping.

Which is the best way?

here is example of xsd:

```
...
<xs:element name="incomeCheck" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="incomeAmount" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="outcomeCheck" type="xs:boolean"/>
...
```

and here what it generates:

```
public class serviceData
    implements Serializable, Equals
{
...
protected boolean incomeCheck;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected BigDecimal incomeAmount;
protected boolean outcomeCheck;
@XmlElement(required = true)
...
```

and I need that it would generate something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="serviceData")
public class serviceData
    implements Serializable, Equals
{
...
@Column(name="incomeCheck")
protected boolean incomeCheck;
@XmlElement(required = true)
@Column(name="incomeAmount")
protected BigDecimal incomeAmount;
@Column(name="outcomeCheck")
protected boolean outcomeCheck;
@XmlElement(required = true)
...
```

To extend my question: As we figured out, we can use HyperJaxb, but can someone tell how to configure pom file, so it would generate these annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use hyperjaxb:

- http://java.net/projects/hyperjaxb

Comment: Sorry, I`m getting lost in this site, can you show me examples or smth?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve that. I think the only approach would be to generate your beans and then annotate them for persistence, but this way you'll have to maintain both your beans and your xsd manually.